# Dependency Injection in ASP.NET MVC architecture with multiple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap

I'm wondering what to do with dependency injection considering the following architecture.

I have 3 projects

`MyProject.UI`
`MyProject.Business`
`MyProject.SomeOtherThing`

StructureMap is being used for dependency injection in `MyProject.UI`.

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());

        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
                x.For<ISomeClass>().Use<SomeClass>();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, the MyProject.SomeOtherThing has some classes in it that are being consumed by `MyProject.Business`. These classes are set up to use DI.

```
namespace MyProject.SomeProject
{
    public SomeClass
    {
        public ISomeDependency SomeDependency { get; set; }

        public SomeClass (ISomeDependency someDependency)
        {
            SomeDependency = someDependency;
        }
    }
}
```

The business layer consumes the class and exposes a service that use `SomeClass` called `SomeService`.

In order for the DI registration to work, `MyProject.UI` has to have a reference to `MyProject.SomeOtherThing`.

I'd like to avoid that. Ideally the UI project would only have a reference to `MyProject.Business`.

What's the best way to handle this situation? Is it to move DI configurations into `MyProject.Business`? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: StructureMap has a nice feature to bind by convention. You should look into that. If you don't like it, then you could move the dependency resolution into an external class library (in the infrastructure of your layered application) and then call some "Initialize" method from the UI layer.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-entry-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue in my current project, as I have a core assembly for UI projects (asp.net MVC, asp.net web api and portable ares of asp.net mvc in separate assemblies), so I decided to put all of the configuration of DI in my Web.Core assembly. there is no other way to handle it.
now your case you don't need to reference `MyProject.SomeOtherThing` in `MyProject.UI` if you don't need it, the best place to the DI configuration for your application is `MyProject.Business`. you just need to register the configuration in `MyProject.UI`, that's all

Answer (score 2):

We created a new project "Binding" that references everything and has the Ninject bindings.  This way, your UI project only needs to know about the Business layer and the Binding layer, not the SomeOtherThing layer.